# How do you solve this trignometric equation?

Tags: education

How to transform equation $(1)$ to equation $(2)$?

> $$u(r,t)=
> -\frac{Ak}{r} \left[ \frac{1}{kr} \cos k(ct-r)-\sin k(ct-r) \right] \tag{1}$$
>
> $$u(r,t)=\frac{A}{r} \sqrt{\frac{1}{r^2}+k^2} \sin[k(ct-r)-\theta] \tag{2}$$
>   where $\tan \theta=\dfrac{1}{kr}$

Original images: [equation $(1)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItBtp.png) and [equation $(2)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOr3T.png)

Answer (score 1):

We can write $$-\frac{Ak}{r}[\frac{1}{kr}\cos k(ct-r) -\sin k(ct-r)]$$ $$\Rightarrow -\frac{A}{r^2}[-\sin k(ct-r)kr +\cos k(ct-r)]$$ $$\Rightarrow -\frac{A\sqrt{k^2r^2+1}}{r^2}[-\sin k(ct-r)\frac{kr}{\sqrt{k^2r^2+1}} + \cos k(ct-r)\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2r^2+1}}]$$

We know that in a triangle with $\tan \theta = \frac{1}{kr}$, $\sin \theta =\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2r^2+1}} , \cos \theta = \frac{kr}{\sqrt{k^2r^2+1}}$. Hence, our equation simplifies to, $$\Rightarrow -\frac{A\sqrt{k^2r^2+1}}{r^2}[-\sin k(ct-r)\cos \theta +\cos k(ct-r)\sin \theta]$$ which upon rearrangement gives us, $$\frac{A}{r}\sqrt{\frac{1}{r^2}+k^2}\sin [k(ct-r)-\theta]$$  Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow thats elegant thanks.